# Percentage mask on some cells of the TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

I have a TStringGrid where I will type in each column a value and I need a mask for the value to appear as a percentage, I am a beginner with Delphi but I saw that there is an OnGetEditMask method but I do not know how to create a mask for the percentage ... then I go manipulate this value into a variable of type Double.
Example
I enter 5,4 and with the mask gets 5,4%

Then how do I get the list data into Double?

Comment: `begin if (ACol = 0) or (Acol=1) then Value := '99,9%' ; end;`
I did it this way but it still does not work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly assigning the `Value` parameter in the `OnGetEditMask` event (assuming your regional settings use decimal comma and not decimal point), repeated here for completeness:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1GetEditMask(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  var Value: string);
begin
  if (ACol = 0) or (ACol = 1) then
    Value := '99,9%';
end;
```

Then, to convert the string content of the cell to a `double`, you need to remove the percent sign from the string before you pass it to, e.g. `StrToFloatDef()`:

For example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  d: double;
  b: boolean;
begin
  b := False;
  s := StringGrid1.Cells[1, 1];
  if s <> '' then
  begin
    if s[Length(s)] = '%' then
    begin
      s := copy(s, 1, Length(s)-1);
      b := true;
    end;
    d := StrToFloatDef(s, 0.0);
    if b then d := d / 100;
  end;
  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(d));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks man, one thing is still not working in relation to the mask ... I would like to type 60 to appear 60,0%, this is not happening only appears to the decimal when I type, example 60,0 ... can improve Is it in the mask?

Comment: Well, you did not express that requirement originally, and it doesn't appear by itself. Possibly you could work it out with the `OnGetEditText` event.